# Python visualize beat frequency in circles or spheres

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyaudio, pyopengl

This is science question and a programming question.

Image of what I would like to happen
[image]

I use pyaudio to create beat frequencies, 20-20000 Hz. But now I would like to visualize these frequencies. Not on a line but in a circle or even better a sphere. There are online tools to do the former, but not the latter. I am interested in dynamic rendering and not static images, that is I want to see the individual frequencies F1 to Fn and the resulting beat frequency move in time and space on screen.

But what library can do this? matplotlib is static (it is not static according to a comment below. Apparently, not known to me at the moment I wrote the question you can animate with matplotlib.), so what library can be used and how? Or perhaps Blender can do it easier?

In matplotlib I can create surfaced shapes, but have not figured out to make them bumpy like golf balls based on the physical attributes of the beat frequency phenomena. In matplotlib I thought it would be something like X1, Y1 = F1 and X2, Y2 = F2 :: X, Y = Fbeat but have not figured out how to do it.

Decision tree for programming brains reading the text.

1 Is the question understood at all? Yes, No?

If No:
Write answer to make DrillBit explain better.

If Yes:

2 Can it be done in matplotlib -how?

If Yes:

Explain to DrillBit IF I have knowledge of how it is done in matplotlib.
else pause 65 hours THEN drink coffee.

If No:

3 Can it be done in other Python library or Blender?

If Yes:

4 Please explain to DrillBit how it could be done or hint at RTFM. Pat self on shoulder and celebrate with cat video.

I have created a flat surface, no bumps from "frequencies"
[image: Flag surface, no bumps from "frequencies"]

Comment: Never thought I'd see Björk mentioned on SO. Didn't know she had a new music video, great! I don't understand at all what you're trying to get out of this here. What is your 2D picture even showing? For e.g. [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/sites/plus.maths.org/files/articles/2011/woodhouse/drum_modes.jpg) are some 2D plate modes. Note that even though the plate is 2D the modes are visualized in 3D. If you wanted to visualize this with spheres, you don't have another dimension to deform the sphere, so your only option is to just have a sphere and color it (but that would be boring).

Comment: Do you just want to take the 1D frequency and wrap it around into a circle? BTW note that this is not a very good question format for this website, it's more for programming problems, and asking for general advice on a problem is considered off-topic. It is a fun question, though.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Yes, initially I just want to wrap straight into round, like a snake biting its tail or a function from a center of rest creating an amplitude difference as a circle or sphere. The plate models you referred to are still flat and not from a center out. I will edit the question so it is not general.

Comment: http://www.pyqtgraph.org/ is quite good at this kind of high speed rendering tasks. Not as powerful as matplotlib, but a lot faster.

Comment: Since we are on a programming site here, first you need to decide whether you want to use matplotlib or any other library. Asking about just anything will not bring you closer to an answer. Assuming you want to ask about matplotlib, the actual problem is not clear. There is no problem of showing an amplitude or frequency spectrum in circular coordinates (possibly offset to obtain a circle). There is also no problem in animating matplotlib plots either. So in order to help you, you need to be clear on what the problem is you are facing and want help with.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use a sum of spherical harmonics. `matplotlib` is not good for 3D surfaces, mayavi may be better and they have an example of spherical harmonics (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_spherical_harmonics.html). You can animate but it may not be fast enough...

Comment: Maybe the way stackoverflow usually works is not clear here. Following the decision tree thingy: (1) read [ask] and [mcve]. (2) Try to plot a sine wave in matplotlib (3) plot a line in circular coordinates or on a polar graph (4) Plot the sine wave in circular coordinates or on a polar graph (5) try to animate a sine wave (6) try to animate the sinewave in circ. coord. or polar graph. There are lots of examples for those steps around; if there is a problem in any of the steps, ask a question about it. If not, step (6) will have solved your problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will try out the circular coordinate solution this week to see if it gets me any closer to my minds vision.

Answer (score 0):

To throw my hat into the ring, I would suggest using a combination of `PyOpenGL` (to create your circle/sphere and do sweet real-time 2D/3D graphics) and `PyQt` (to create an OpenGL context to house your visualization as well as to provide a user interface for input). **Note that if you choose to go this route, while this will be very flexible, be prepared to write LOTS of stuff from scratch.** You could probably also take a look at the existing combination of those two libraries as suggested in the comments by @Jeronimo, `PyQtGraph`, which could be more straightforward.

Let's take a step back from visualization technologies though and mathematically think ***how*** we are going to draw this on the screen. From your question, it looks like your goal is the following:

> I want to see the individual frequencies F1 to Fn and the resulting beat frequency move in **time and space** on screen.

This is a little vague and what exactly you are expecting to draw should be cleared up in your question. For my own sanity's sake, let's look at the "simpler" case of a circle with a variable radius. Let the circle have a `radius r` which can vary by an amplitude `+/- a`. This variation can show us the waveform. Starting from 0 to 2*pi radians and going around the circle's perimeter counter-clockwise, we could simulate a time range `t0` to `t1` along the circumference of the circle. We could then increment the value of `t0` (and `t1`) in real-time, shifting our range of simulated values.

Playing around with [this demo](https://academo.org/demos/wave-interference-beat-frequency/) one issue that I see with just "wrapping" your line around and creating a perfect [ouroboros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros) is that there will be **discontinuities at the wrapping point**, unless you change the circumference such that it is perfectly divisible by your beat frequency's period.

Furthermore, the result I got (see code below) is fairly disappointing to look at. Why? Incrementing the time makes the circle just spin around (think of it as our wave just propagating along the surface of the circle). Anyways, here is what the (messy) code looks like; hopefully it provides some ideas on how to approach creating your own visualization from scratch:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor, QStatusBar, QSizePolicy
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *
import math
import numpy as np
import sys
import time

class Waveform(object):
    """
    Defines a class Waveform where waves are of the form: y = sin(2*pi*f*t).
    """
    def __init__(self, frequency):
        self.f = frequency

    def calc_points(self, t0, t1, n):
        """
        Samples at n points from [t0, t1] and calculates the appropriate amplitude "a" value.
        Returns the data as a list of tuples.
        """
        data = []
        for i in range(n):
            frac = (t1 - t0)/(n - 1)
            t = i * frac + t0 
            a = math.sin(2 * math.pi * self.f * t)
            data.append((i, t, a))
        return data

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.widget = GLWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class GLWidget(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(1000/60)#so-called "60 fps"

    def initializeGL(self):
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

    def paintGL(self):#Important part of the code (circle drawing stuff) here!
        curr_time = time.time()
        delta = (curr_time - self.start_time)
        t0, t1 = 0 + delta, 0.05 + delta
        f1 = 500
        f2 = 490
        num_slices = 1001
        radius = 200
        amplitude = 5
        a = Waveform(f1)
        b = Waveform(f2)
        data1 = a.calc_points(t0, t1, num_slices)
        data2 = b.calc_points(t0, t1, num_slices)

        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN)
        glColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(w/2.0, h/2.0, 0)
        for point in range(len(data1)):
            i1, p1, a1 = data1[point]
            i2, p2, a2 = data2[point]
            t = p1
            a = a1 + a2#adding the waveforms together
            frac = (t - t0)/(t1 - t0)
            angle = 2 * math.pi * frac
            r = radius + amplitude * a
            x = r * math.cos(angle) + (w/2)
            y = r * math.sin(angle) + (h/2)
            glVertex3f(x, y, 0)
        glEnd()

    def update(self):
        self.updateGL()#seems odd, but calling this causes a paintGL() call behind the scenes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Beat Frequency App")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The academo tool was exactly what I was thinking of. The ouroboros problem is where the physics kicks in. If radius and wavelength are in harmony you have a perfect "sphere", but if not you have a discrepancy. Is it solved by photon emission or excitation? I will try your solution as soon as I am at a larger computer.